Google Meet API
Has anyone successfully implemented and used the new Google Meet API (https://developers.google.com/meet/api/guides/overview) in Django Rest Framework? I am interested in implementing the Google Meet API in Django Rest Framework and would like to know about any experiences or best practices in doing so.
I have tried to use the API and I want t make a google meet link automatically but there is no method in the word with conference part that supports that
